# Multi-row headers and excel 2010 sort/filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet which uses 2 rows for header information and some of the columns have the 2 rows merged together as one cell. I a multiple columns merged together in the first row, but the second row underneath without the columns merged together. Filtering implicitly is assuming only 1 row of header information. Sorting has a header row check-box but that only toggles treating the first row as a header.

Is there a way to make excel treat the first two rows as headers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Unmerge the headers that are merged.
2. Select your data manually, from the second row downwards.
3. Apply the filter.
4. Re-merge the headers.

The filter dropdowns should stay on row 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the value in advanced filter Field Range is set to include the rows below your header rows.

You can set this value manually or use a macro to do it for you.

EG in my spreadsheet, I have rows 1-3 as multi line headers. I constantly add rows of data below.  The following macro sets the Filter Field Range to include rows 4 - to the last populated row on the spreadsheet. This ensures that any sort will treat row 3 as the header (provided you check the 'my data includes headers' checkbox)

(I incorporate this at the end of a more complex macro, to ensure that the Field Range property is always up to date after data imports - easier than remembering to manually re-set it each time)

```
Sub selector()

Sheets("AESummary").Select
Sheets("AESummary").Activate

' find last row containing data in column A (column A will always be populated in this dataset)

Set WS = Worksheets("AESummary")
With WS
    Set LastCellC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        LastCellRowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(LastCellC.Row) + 1
   End With

' set the filter Field Range value to include Row 4 to the last populated row in the worksheet

        Rows("4:" & LastCellRowNumber).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, better late than never

Define a local (worksheet) name "Database" from the last header row to the last table row. That is:

Formulas » Name Manager » New » Name:Database, Scope:{sheet name}, Refers to:{select all table and manually change first cell's row}

Answer (score 0):

sad to say that XLS 2016 still doesnt handle this OOB.
there is another workaround to this, which should also work with previous versions:

separate the last header row from the other ones with an empty line and hide this one. then XLS has no trouble in recognizing this one row as he header.